# How to query Google Drive API whether a folder has children, without fetching them?

Tags: google-drive-api

Given the ID of a Google Drive folder, I want to query the API whether that folder has any children.  I don't want to get a list of those children, just an indication of whether there are any.  Is there some form of the Google Drive API query language that would return that?

It would be even better if a single query could handle checks for multiple folders, by ID.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Probably the most efficient alternative would be to list the Children feed with a maxResults=1. If you do this, be careful not to simply count the number of children returned. Because of the way Drive works, it is possible to have zero children, but also a non-null nextPageToken indicating that there subsequent pages which do have children.